# How to write Sentinel windows scan query

Tags: azure-sentinel

I'm writing a query currently to trigger a scan on Windows 10 Laptops,when a Virus is detected on that machine.

This is my query:
`DeviceEvents | where ActionType == "AntivirusDetection" | project DeviceName, InitiatingProcessFileName, InitiatingProcessFolderPath, InitiatingProcessVersionInfoOriginalFileName, InitiatingProcessVersionInfoProductName, InitiatingProcessAccountName` 
Does someone have a better idea, how I could write the query?

Thank you in advance for your contribution.